# Timespan in typescript

Tags: angular

I'm building a web app using Angular + Typescript. And I have ASP.NET Core Web API, I'm trying to show in front end time in this format `10:10:10` but it shows me in this format

```json
{
 "Hours":16,
 "Minutes":8,
 "Seconds":45,
 "Milliseconds":0,
 "Ticks":581250000000,
 "Days":0,
 "TotalDays":0.6727430555555556,
 "TotalHours":16.145833333333332,
 "TotalMilliseconds":58125000,
 "TotalMinutes":968.75,
 "TotalSeconds":58125
}
```

How do I display timespan in typescript?

My html Code

```
         <ng-container matColumnDef="startday">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
          {{'::Startday' | abpLocalization}}
        </th>
        <pre mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
          {{ element.startday| json}}
        </pre>
      </ng-container>
```

Comment: you have object with Hours, MInutes, Secodns...You can create: let time:string = object.Hours + ":" + object.Minutes + ":" + object.Secodns. Do you need dinamic clock or just need to show what you get from api endponit?

Comment: I just need to show what i get from api in my frontend table,the problem is angular don't recognise type timespan

Comment: Use this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65595154/4799922. You need convert resposne data in componetn.

Answer (score 1):

You simply can use hours, mins, secs from object and concatenate it in one string

Also I added method `getString()` that convert one number to format `01`, if 12 it will be the same 12

instead of `1:1:1` we got `01:01:01`

```js
const time = {
 "Hours":16,
 "Minutes":8,
 "Seconds":45,
 "Milliseconds":0,
 "Ticks":581250000000,
 "Days":0,
 "TotalDays":0.6727430555555556,
 "TotalHours":16.145833333333332,
 "TotalMilliseconds":58125000,
 "TotalMinutes":968.75,
 "TotalSeconds":58125
};

function getString(number) {
  return number.toString().padStart(2, "0") // converts 2 to 02, 7 to 07
}

const formattedTime = `${getString(time.Hours)}:${getString(time.Minutes)}:${getString(time.Seconds)}`;

console.log(formattedTime)
```

Comment: so if it helps you, you can mark the answer like correct